# Over-riding update method in django modelViewSet

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble defining an update method on a serializer class in django. This is my basic model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Items(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    item = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 20,decimal_places =2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

and the below is my serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source = 'category.category',read_only = True)
    category_pk = serializers.IntegerField(source = 'category.pk')

    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ('pk','category','category_pk','item','rate',)

    def update(self,instance,validated_data):

        category_pk = validated_data.get('category_pk',instance.category_pk)
        instance.category = Category.objects.get(pk = category_pk)
        instance.item = validated_data.get('item',instance.item)
        instance.rate = validated_data.get('rate',instance.rate)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

I'm getting an error when using the PUT method from AJAX stating that the Item object does not have a category_pk field (but i'm not including that in the instance.save() method)

below is my AJAX request

```
$('#update-item').on('click',function(){

    var dat = {
      'category':$("#category-box").find('option[value='+cat_pk+']').text(),
      'category_pk':$('#category-box').val(),
      'item':$('#Items').val(),
      'rate':$('#Rate').val()
      };
      console.log(dat);

    $.ajax({
      type : 'PUT',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/billing/items/'+pk+'/',
      data : JSON.stringify(dat),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      crossDomain:true,
      success : function(json){
        alert('ok');

      },
      error : function(json){
        alert('error with PUT')
      }
    });
  });
```

I'm over-riding the update method because rest framework threw an error intially stating that it cant write nested fields.

KJ

Comment: Have you inspected and verified that `$('#category-box').val()` contains data? What does it contain? I don't know what you're holding in `cat_pk` or what the difference is between that and `category_pk`, but the error makes it seem that the issue is you're not passing the correct data to `category_pk` on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default DRF will use the pk for the category field on a ModelSerializer, but in your case you are setting the category field as read_only=True, and on your model is no category_pk field. I would change the serializer like this, and then post the pk to the category field and not the category_pk field. You can then also remove the update method override.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # I assume you changed the category field to readonly to display the text of the category
    category_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='category.category')

    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ('pk','category','category_name','item','rate',)
```